# How to structure two classes that "intersect" and output certain values (Mediator design pattern)?

Tags: c#, class, oop, mediator

I have two classes: `User` and `Site`. `User` and `Site` have a many-to-many relationship. A `Site` object S has a property indicating whether or not a `User` U should be validated before U is added to S. To validate a `User`, the application retrieves validation rules from the `Site` and checks to see that the `User`'s properties' values match the validation rules' values. If they all match/pass, the `User` is "valid" to be added to that `Site`.

How would you structure this relationship? My first thought is to create an intermediate class (i.e. Mediator design pattern?) that has a field of type `IEnumerable<User>` and `Site` so I can encapsulate the `Site` validation setting retrieval. Also, I'm thinking of adding an "IsValid" property to the `User` class. Is that all I need? I want to make sure things are not tightly coupled.

Thoughts?

Here's similar code I wrote up:

```
public class User
{
    public int _userId;
    public string _fname;
    public string _lname;

    public User(string connectionString, int id)
    {
        using (var dc = new DataContext(connectionString))
        {
            var user = dc.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.ID == id);
            _userId = user.ID;
            _fname = user.FName;
            _lname = user.LName;
        }
    }

    public bool IsValidUser(int siteId)
    {
        bool isValid = true;
        // logic here probably won't change
        var conditions = Site.GetConditions(_userId);
        // e.g. checks _fname, _lname
        return Site.UserMeetsConditions(_id, conditions);
    }
}

public class Site
{
    public int _siteId;
    public List<Setting> _siteSettings;

    public Site(string connectionString, int id)
    {
        using (var dc = new DataContext(connectionString))
        {
            var site = dc.Sites.SingleOrDefault(u => u.ID == id);
            _siteId = site.ID;
        }
    }

    public void SetSiteSettings(string connectionString)
    {
        using (var dc = new DataContext(connectionString))
        {
            _siteSettings = dc.SiteSettings.Select(s => s).ToList();
        }
    }

    public bool SiteRequiresValidityCheck()
    {
        return _siteSettings.Any(s => s.SettingID = 100 && s.Value == true);
    }
}

public Validator
{
    public List<User> users;
    public bool _requiresValidityCheck;

    public bool UsersAreValid(int siteId)
    {
        bool usersAreValid = true;
        if (_requiresValidityCheck)
        {
            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                if (!user.IsValid)
                {
                    usersAreValid = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return usersAreValid;
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    string cs = myconnectionstring;
    var user1 = new User(cs, 1);
    var user2 = new User(cs, 2);
    List<User> users = new List<User>() { user1, user2 };
    var site = new Site(cs, 10);
    site.SetSiteSettings(cs);
    var validator = new Validator();
    validator.Users = users;
    validator._requiresValidityCheck = site.SiteRequiresValidityCheck();

    bool usersAreValid = validator.UsersAreValid(site._siteId);

}
```

Comment: Would be easier if you just _post the code_ rather than explaining it in a paragraph

Comment: It's company code - not sure if I can.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a POCO class or a MODEL you could use DataAnnotations on your class attributes.
Like user

```
[Required]
```

etc attributes for each attribute.
Data annotations also has support for cross attribute checking that you can implement those too.
take a look at them here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590%28VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: Good suggestion, but I'm actually less concerned about the `User`<->`Site` validation comparison than finding the best way to encapsulate the retrieval of `Site` validation settings and maintaining the relationship between `User` and `Site`. Maybe I'll edit my post to reflect this.

Comment: How does this address _"How would you structure this relationship?  My first thought is to create an intermediate class (i.e. Mediator design pattern?) that has a field of type IEnumerable<User> and Site"_